# Bean-Managed EB3 with jdbc persistency

Tags: java, jdbc, ejb, ejb-3.0, entity-bean

I was trying to write a bean-managed persistent entity bean in EJB3, without using JPA, but with using jdbc connection to postgres. My question is, because it is BMP, the jdbc methods are written in it, should I create a session bean and write the methods in it, and keep the @Entity above the entity bean I created, or how to do it? what is a good start? it is for testing purposes.

Thank you in advance